# SSL error!, your connection is encrypted with modern cryptography

Tags: magento, ssl, encryption

Hello i have an issue with my domain and ssl, when you enter to https://www.limitx.com.mx you can see a error with a ssl encryption, your connection is encrypted with modern cryptography, how i can solve this? i dont know how to fix this issue, i hope can help me. Bes regards guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two resources on your home page that are served over HTTP (mixed content).

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://limitx.com.mx/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet
>   'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900,300,700'. This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

This is coming from the main file that is generating the HTML:

```
<link href='fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,300'; rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

You'll need to change this to be

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,300'; rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://limitx.com.mx/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://limitx.panamerik.net/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/images/infortis/_shared/generic-nav/buscar.png'.
>   This content should also be served over HTTPS.

This is coming from https://limitx.com.mx/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/css/styles.css

```
.form-search .button {
...
background-image: url(http://limitx.panamerik.net/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/images/infortis/_shared/generic-nav/buscar.png);
...
}
```

You cannot use an HTTPS version of this URL as the certificate for http://limitx.panamerik.net/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/images/infortis/_shared/generic-nav/buscar.png does not match the host.

You can copy this file (buscar.png) locally, perhaps under skin/frontend/ultimo/default/images/infortis/_shared/generic-nav/ and change the CSS to be

```
.form-search .button {
...
background-image: url(../images/infortis/_shared/generic-nav/buscar.png);
...
}
```

Comment: Dude so much thanks!! its works fine! really thanks for take time to reply me and thanks for help really you are the best of best!, really dude thanks again! its solved!

Answer (score 1):

Well the issue is that other objects on your page are not using ssl, do you have any embeded links that have http instead of say https? I would check those images, they are most likely the culprit. Instead of using relative paths try hardcoding all the images with https://url to image/ alright? That should fix ya up good. Nice site btw.

For your Firefox issues: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/967766
The only way for websites to "supply ownership information" would be through a secure connection and an "Extended Validation Certificate" which will cost a few hundred USD and upwards per year at the relevant certificate authorities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate

Google Issues: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617?p=ui_security_indicator&rd=1
Your connection to the site is encrypted, but Google Chrome has detected mixed content on the page. Be careful if you're entering information on this page. Mixed content can provide a loophole for someone to manipulate the page. This content could be third- party images or ads embedded on the page.

Internet Explorer.....doesnt see any issues at all.

Comment: <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: It takes a time to change the ssl status? or is instantaneous?

Comment: Not 100% sure, its our browsers checking your site, not the SSL, so it should be quick. Download firefox and chrome and you will get a better understanding about all the small issues. Just change those links to https:// and your on to a start. <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: But here can see more details about the error, but i dont understand how i can fix, here the details of SSL https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=limitx.com.mx

Comment: This isn't an SSL configuration issue (although your setup is far from ideal -- another thing for another day). As Scott indicated, you'll need to change HTTP references to be HTTPS. I've provided two places where this needs to happen in my answer. You may need to do this in other places if you see the same warning/ error on other pages.

Comment: Essentially SSL is tricky for a number of reasons, you have just hit the top of the iceberg. Get everything over to SSL via https and your off to a good start.